# Sanitizing SQL query with PDO and replacing deprecated mysql_real_esape_string to keep PHP code secure

Tags: php, security, pdo

How can I replace mysql_real_escape_string in PDO to keep my code still secure:

(mysql_real_escape_string no longer supported in PHP v7.x)

I would appreciate if somebody could provide an example for this code line:
"ORDER BY " . mysql_real_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";"

Full code below:

```
 public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="pageID ASC" ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pagePublicationDate) AS pagePublicationDate FROM web_pages
            ORDER BY " . mysql_real_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $article = new cmsEngine( $row );
      $list[] = $article;
    }

    // Now get the total number of website pages that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
  }
```

Comment: Not duplicated as not same question in my query.. Online examples and StackOverflow topics don't contain samples of sanitizing variables in SQL query.. (please refer to my example).

Comment: There are *different* answers. Check the [third one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/285587).

Comment: Also note that your `mysql_real_escape_string($order)` **did not sanitize anything** and your code were vulnerable.  So you better not to look for replacement

Comment: Comments without facts doesn't make any sense.. Can somebody explain to me?

Comment: You can try here, [A slightly non-trivial SQL injection example. String escaping](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#escaping) and tell me whether it's convincing. I am the author of the article and eager to get any feedback.

Comment: Great article, I have seen it before. However as I am not pro developer, I am learning by examples.. So would like to understand what is wrong with my code, am I need to backstick sql table items and etc? I was reading following: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group + your article

Comment: You need rather this [one](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#identifiers). In short, you cannot sanitize an arbitrary query part like `pageID ASC` at all. It's just impossible. But you can whitelist its parts, the field name and the direction separately.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into this. But wasn't sure how to transform my existing code to sample you supplied. Also I am reading these samples multi times and still can't understand. I have removed and mysql_real_string_escape function completely now and just quering against $orders variable. I still can't understand why my code is vulnerable - I have performed various SQL pen test against web app and none of them showed vulnerability in this particular query..

Comment: What it is also confusing on these internet articles, that most authors provides only bits of code (I mean not giving full picture), puzzling doesn't help to understand efficiently.

Comment: Just make it `pageID ASC;DROP TABLE web_pages#` and see

Comment: Just tested with sqlmap: 14:55:18] [CRITICAL] all tested parameters appear to be not injectable.

Comment: I don't know this sqlmap thing is but if you make your $order as shown above you will see how much protection you can get from mysql_real_escape_string($order).

Comment: Is my function will be safe if I will replace $order with static item, so instead: mysql_real_escape_string($order). I would have:    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pagePublicationDate) AS pagePublicationDate FROM `web_pages`
            ORDER BY pageID ASC LIMIT :numRows";

Comment: Yes, of course this way it will be secure

Comment: Oh, great! Thanks for explanation, now I understand. What about if I still want to keep it as variable - what would be safe option? Would it be possible to have an example? Maybe I should extra binding something like: $st->bindValue( ":pageID", $orders, PDO::PARAM_INT );

Comment: No, you cannot bind anything beside a string and a nubmer. And your pageID ASC is neither. Start from keeping ASC in place while treat ordering field using examples I liked to before.

Comment: Great, what about my other variable: $numRows ? Am I right thinking that it will remain safe as it is being binded to integer? $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );

Comment: yes, of course, that's canonical way to do that. however, you can make your code 3 times shorter. PDO can create object right off request. Basically you will need 3 commands, `$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute([$numRows]); $list = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'cmsEngine');`

Comment: Thanks for all your explanations Sir! Appreciate your assistance and value people like you!

Comment: Ok, I will reply soon. Cleaning up the comments.